# Creating Stacked Bar chart with line graph using jfreechart and taking values from database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, jfreechart

I want to create a stacked bar chart with line graph on it using jfreechart by taking values from db.

Basically, I want to show two values on the bar - failed values and success values on top of that.

A line graph will touch all the bars and its value will be the summation of failed and success values for that respective hour.

Also, I want one horizontal line which will represent the average of all the values , i.e. total count of (failed+success) values

This Stacked Bar will have per hour values , i.e on the x-axis hours count will be present.
Y -axis should have no. of values.

I have written the following  code for creating only StackedBarChart, but its not generating the graph

As I am new to jfreechart, I am not sure how to come up with the code. Any help would be appreciated.

code.....

```
      String query1 = "select * from table1";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(query1);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            System.out.println("Creating Graph of hourly count");

            while (rs.next())
            {
                Number a = Long.parseLong(rs.getString("SuccessValues"));
                String b = rs.getString("FailureValues");
                String c = rs.getString("Hours");
                dataset.setValue(a, b, c);
            }
            final String title = "Per Hour Count";
            final String Xaxis = "Time";
            final String Yaxis = "Orders";
            barChartDisp(title,Xaxis,Yaxis,dataset);

    private void barChartDisp(String title, String xaxis, String yaxis, DefaultCategoryDataset dataset) {
        try{
            JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(title, xaxis, yaxis, dataset,
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            File BarChart = new File("BarChart.jpeg");
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(BarChart, barChart, width, height);
            }}
```

Comment: Exactly what are you stuck on? Break up your problem into two parts: 1) getting the data from the database, and 2) creating a chart from the data.

Comment: I am able to get the data from the database ..but I am not sure how to code to create the chart.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that uses representative, hard-coded data, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart).